# why document.getElementsByName().length always return 0?

Tags: getelementsbyname

I'm new to JavaScript. In the following code `getElementsByName("li").length` always returns 0 although there are many `<li>`-tags in my HTML, why?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var len = document.getElementsByName('li').length;
    alert(len);
})

art of my HTML:

<body>
    <ul>
        <li>aaaaaa</li>
        <li>bbbbbb</li>
        <li>cccccc</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

`document.getElementsByName('li')`

with

`document.getElementsByTagName('li')`

This is happening cause you are selecting by `tag name` and not by `name` ! You are using wrong function!

Comment: If you use this method, you will also have to specify which list item you are trying to get the length of

Comment: John, as per question I believe he is confused with `getElementByName` and `getElementByTagName`  , and he is just testing out the functions...

Comment: yes.you are right .i use the wrong function.Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

The method you are attempting to use is trying to find a specific element by its name.

None of your list items have a name, to do this you should update your code so that your items have names.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var len = document.getElementsByName('list_item_1').length;
    alert(len);
})    

<li name="list_item1">aaaaaa</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this because `getElementsByTagName()` returns NodeList so you can iterate over it like an array or get the length.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var listElements = document.getElementById('list').getElementsByTagName("li");
    alert(listElements.length);
})
```

```html
<body>
    <ul id="list">
        <li >aaaaaa</li>
        <li>bbbbbb</li>
        <li>cccccc</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

`getElementsByName()` although also returns NodeList but it returns list of all *same* name elements in the *whole* document so to make this work you need to give same name to all list items.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var len = document.getElementsByName('name').length;
    alert(len);
});
```

```html
<body>
    <ul>
        <li name="name">aaaaaa</li>
        <li name="name">bbbbbb</li>
        <li name="name">cccccc</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```